# How to delete emojis from Youtube filenames?

Tags: sed, perl, ascii

Im trying to remove emoticons from this Youtube filename:

> وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4

Im using `perl -p -e 's/[^[:ascii:]]//g'` and `tr -dc '[:print:]'` but got this;

> & -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4

How to delete emoticons and keep Arabic characters?

Comment: `| tr -d ''`?

Comment: @Cyrus This was just an example, I have a hundred of videos with many emoji characters in filenames.

Comment: I have the same problem using `yt-dlp` extensively :)

Comment: @SridharSarnobat `yt-dlp` has a `--restrict-filenames` option can do the trick.

Comment: @s3idani - oh fantastic, I wish I knew this sooner. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to delete emojis and keep arabic characters in filename using `sed`:

> echo "وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4" | sed
> 's/\xf0\x9f/\r&/g; s/\s*\r.//g'

output

> وسائل الاتصال الحديثة & -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4

I know this might not be the best and cleanest way but it fix my current issue.

Comment: Could you please explain `sed 's/\xf0\x9f/\r&/g; s/\s*\r.//g'`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the status of multi-byte character support in GNU `tr`.

In `perl`, you will need to set at least the stdin and stdout streams UTF-8 aware using the [-C perlrun option](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber%2Flist%5D). You can then use unicode properties as described in the [perluniprops documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops) - there is even an `\p{Emoji}` codepoint group. So for example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4' | 
    perl -C -pe '$_ =~ s/[\p{Emoji}]//g'
وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOxJf.mp
```

Unfortunately it looks like `\p{Emoji}` includes at least the decimal digits - although you can exclude those using the (currently experimental) *regex_sets* feature, for example:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4' | 
    perl -Mexperimental=regex_sets -C -pe 's/(?[\p{Emoji} - \p{ASCII}])//g'
وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4
```

At least in File::Rename version 1.30, you can make the perl-based `rename` command encoding-aware in a similar manner to perl's `-C` via its `-u` option:

```
   -u, --unicode [encoding]
           Treat filenames as perl (unicode) strings when running the
           user-supplied code.

           Decode/encode filenames using encoding, if present.

           encoding is optional: if omitted, the next argument should be
           an option starting with '-', for instance -e.
```

So given

```
$ ls *.mp4
'وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4'
```

then

```
$ rename -n -u utf8 'use experimental qw(regex_sets); s/(?[\p{Emoji} - \p{ASCII}])//g' *.mp4
rename(وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4, وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4)
```

You could instead specify character ranges to keep ex.

```
$ rename -n -u utf8 's/[^\p{ASCII}\p{Arabic}]//g' *.mp4
rename(وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4, وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4)
```

or

```
$ rename -n -u utf8 'use experimental qw(regex_sets); s/(?[\P{ASCII} & \P{Arabic}])//g' *.mp4
rename(وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4, وسائل الاتصال الحديثة  &   -eYrBcHOx2Jf.mp4)
```

which doesn't seem to have the same issue with the `4` character.